# Inserting value from filter in Exception value

Tags: java, java-8

I have an enum Fruit containing fruit, category.

```
public enum Fruit {

    MANGO("mango", "A"), APPLE("apple", "A"), CHERRY("cherry", "B"), BERRY("berry", "B");

    private String fruit;
    private String category;

    private Fruit(String fruit, String category) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public static Fruit forValue(final String fruit, final List<String> categories){
             return Arrays.stream(Fruit.forValues()).filter(item ->               item.getFruit().equals(fruit)).findFirst().filter(item -> categories.contain(item.getCategory(category)).orElseThrow(() -> new IlleagalArgumentException("Fruit only allowed with category +  " item.getCategory());
}
}
```

Let's say I want to run this -

```
   List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
   categories.add("A");
   categories.add("Z");

   Fruit.forValue("berry");
```

In this case, I want to throw exception - Fruit only allowed with category B
(because category for berry is B)

But this - item.getCategory() - will not run.. So, Is there any way to output the category like this

Expecting output - Fruit only allowed with category B

Comment: Sure, just take out of the Optional and write normal `if`s.

Comment: Any chance with Optonal? @shmosel

Comment: You could throw the exception in `filter` but then it's not really a filter.

Answer (score 0):

At first, in your code, I see that the part where you throw the exception is missing a parenthesis at the end.

`return Arrays.stream(Fruit.forValues()).filter(item ->               item.getFruit().equals(fruit)).findFirst().filter(item -> categories.contain(item.getCategory(category)).orElseThrow(() -> new IlleagalArgumentException("Fruit only allowed with category +  " item.getCategory());`

Also, why do you use a parameter in `item.getCategory(category)`  if your method doesn't have one.
For your question, modifying this would make this code work, but you can also use try and catch as an alternative.